# The joint distribution of $X_{n}$ and $X$ must be defined to check convergence in probability.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

We say $X_{n}$ converges to X in probability if for every $\epsilon$>0, $P\{|X_{n}-X|>\epsilon\}\to 0 \;as\; n \to\infty$

The book I am reading provides the following example to illustrate the joint probability between $X_{n}$ and $X$ must be defined in order to check convergence in probability:
$X_{1},X_{2},...$ are i.i.d. normal, $N(0,1)$. 
Then $X_{n}\to X_{1}$ in distribution but not in probability.

It is not clear to me as to why the joint probability between $X_{n}$ and $X$ must be defined and where it fits in this example.

Comment: If $X$ and $X_n$ don't have a joint distribution, what would $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)$ mean?